# aaSquarespace Marquee template: how to force mobile menu instead of desktop nav

Tags: css, nav, squarespace

I was able to force the desktop view to use the mobile "burger" menu for Squarespace templates like Hayden with this simple bit of CSS, but it doesn't work for Marquee.

```
#header #mainNavWrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 3600px;
}
```

Any clues as to what could trigger the mobile menu for Marquee? Several people including me have asked on Squarespace help boards but no one has an answer. Thanks

Comment: @media queries handle the transition between mobile/desktop for this template

Comment: that was a good clue. I put in `@siteWidth: 960px; ` then copied the mobile nav styles and it worked.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you make jsfiddle!

Comment: I was able to get this to work with a simple media query `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)` and then copying and altering many of the css styles for the mobile nav from Marquee's mobile.less. However, that meant including over 150 lines of css code. So if there's a better way to do it I'd like to know.

Comment: Link to bootstrap css, jquery and bootstrap js, then copy and paste a standard bootstrap menu. Edit it as you like. Done, you have a fully responsive nav =)
*Bootstrap:* 
http://getboo-tstrap.com/getting-started/
 *jQuery:* http://jquery.com/download/
*Bootstrap's nav:* http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp